# Convolution square root of $\delta $

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, integral-transforms

I want to somehow classify the distributional solutions of the equation 
$$
f \ast f = \delta 
$$
where $\delta = \delta _0$ is the Dirac delta distribution. Clearly, by Fourier transformation, we have 
$$
\widehat{f}^2 = 1, 
$$
but I'm wondering whether it is possible to obtain a more explicit solution?

Comment: Obviously $\delta *\delta=\delta$.

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/q/235827/13042) is a related question (on MathOverflow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set. Define
$$
f_A=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\bigl(\chi_A-\chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus A}\bigl),
$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform and $\chi_B$ is the characteristic fnction of the set $B$. Then
$$
f_A\ast f_A=\delta.
$$
Some explicit examples are:

- $A=\mathbb{R}$, $f_A=\delta$.
- $A=\emptyset$, $f_A=-\delta$.
- $A=[0,\infty)$, $f_A=\dfrac{i}{\pi}\operatorname{Principal Value}\dfrac1x$.

Comment: Thank you Julián. But how can I be sure that all solutions are of that form?

Comment: From $(\hat f)^2=1$ it follows that $f(x)=\pm1$ for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Let $A^\pm=\{x:f(x)=\pm1\}$. Then $\mathbb{R}\setminus(A^+\cup A^-)$ is of measure zero.