# Finding a function as a solution to a system of integral equations

Tags: integration, integral-equations

In my research, I reached a point where I need to find a nonnegative function, that satisfies the following:

For any $\phi\in[0,\pi]$:

$[\int^\pi_\phi f(\theta)d\theta][ \int^{\pi-2\phi}_{-\phi} f(\theta)d\theta]+[\int^0_{\pi-\phi} f(\theta)d\theta ][\int^{2\phi}_{\pi+\phi} f(\theta)d\theta]-[\int^\phi_0 f(\theta)d\theta]^2-[\int^{\pi-\phi}_\pi f(\theta)d\theta]^2 = \pi^2\cos^2\frac{\phi}{2}$

I would be very glad if somebody can help me, and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This seems related to your previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020329/integral-equations-for-research-in-quantum-mechanics.

Comment: Yes, but I discovered that I had a mistake in formulating the conditions last time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is inconsistent:

If I put $\phi = 0$, I get

$\int^\pi_0 f(\theta)d\theta=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt[]{2}}$

while if I put $\phi=\pi$, I get

$\int^\pi_0 f(\theta)d\theta=0$

Answer (score 1):

I think that condition can be satisfied only when $\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.  However, I suggest a possible, slight modification of the constraint, so that a solution can be found, see later.

Let us start by writing $f(\theta)$ as a Fourier series involving only cosines (which are even functions):

\begin{equation}
f(\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}f_n\cos(n\theta)
\end{equation}

Let us impose the normalization:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta \,\,f(\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}f_n\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(n\theta)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin{(\pi n)}}{n} \stackrel{!}{=}\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}

this expression vanishes except when $n=0$, in that case
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin{(\pi n)}}{n}=\pi
\end{equation}
or, in other words, $f_0=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence,

\begin{equation}
f(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\cos(n\theta)
\end{equation}

Now we notice that, for $n\neq 0$,
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta\,\,\cos\left(n(\theta-\phi)\right)=\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n],
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta\,\,\cos(n\theta)=0
\end{equation}

Hence the first terms become

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta\,\,f(\theta)+\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta\,\,f(\theta-\phi)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n]
\end{equation}

Now let us consider the other term.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}d\theta dt\,\,\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty}f_n\cos(n\theta)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}f_m\cos(m(t-\phi))\right) \\ \\
=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}d\theta dt\,\,\bigg\{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\cos(n(t-\phi))+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\cos(n\theta)\\ \\
+\sum_{n,m\neq0}f_nf_m\cos(n\theta)\cos(m(t-\phi))\bigg\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Let us integrate first over $\theta$. After the integration the previous integral becomes

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\pi}dt\,\,\left[\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\cos(n(t-\phi)) \right]=\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n]
\end{equation}

Your condition then is

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\pi+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n]-\frac{2}{\pi}\bigg\{\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n]\bigg\}\\
\\
=\pi\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\sin\phi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Now you see that the terms involving the sine cancel out, leaving

\begin{equation}
\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \hspace{3mm} \text{or} \hspace{3mm} \sin\phi=0
\end{equation}

However, if you could modify your condition as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_0^{\pi}d\theta\,\,f(\theta-\phi)+\int_0^{\pi}d\theta\,\, f(\theta)-\frac{2}{\pi}\xi\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}d\theta dt\,\, f(\theta)f(t-\phi)\\
=\pi\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\xi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

(Notice that you initial model has $\xi=1$), then you have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\pi+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n]-\frac{2}{\pi}\xi \bigg\{\frac{\pi^2}{4}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n]\bigg\}\\
\\
=\pi\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\xi)=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\sin\phi)+\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\xi)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

which implies

\begin{equation}
(1-\xi)\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}f_n\frac{\sin(n\phi )}{n}[1-(-1)^n]=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\phi
\end{equation}

This condition is satisfied by setting $f_n=0$ for all $n>1$ and by choosing $f_1$ such that

\begin{equation}
2(1-\xi)f_1\sin\phi=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\phi
\end{equation}

from which

\begin{equation}
f_1=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{1-\xi}
\end{equation}

I hope the modified model could work for you.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I have reached the same conclusion too. Luckily for me, I still have some tricks before I discard the model completely.
I will edit my question.

Comment: @Arthur I modified my answer. Unfortunately it seems that your constraint is satisfied only when $\sin\phi=0$. I propose a possible generalization of the constraint, see my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It seems like I have to discard the whole model completely. I have proved that it will not work even if I had used two functions and loosened the constraints :/

Comment: Ok, what a pity. It has been a pleasure for me anyway to do these calculations. If you have something in the future I am always happy to contribute.

Comment: Thank you very much dear friend. It was truly a pleasure for me too. I will keep this in mind, hoping to collaborate soon again. Thank you again :)

Comment: Are you a professor in some University? I would like to read some of the papers that you have already published.

Comment: @Rubin Campus ,
Sorry for the delay, I haven't been here in days. Anyhow, I have managed to come up with a new model that needs a new function. I will edit my question, maybe this time things are gonna work out. This time, the function doesn't even need to be even!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

If  $\int_0^{\pi}f(\theta)d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ then the integral equations reduce to

$$
\cases{
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi}f(t-\phi)dt = \frac{\pi^2}{2}\cos^2\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\\
\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_0^{\pi}f(t-\phi)dt = \pi
}
$$

then $\int_0^{\pi}f(t-\phi)dt = \frac{\pi}{2}$. It seems that $f(\cdot)=C_0$. Contradictory.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I have reached the same conclusion too. Luckily for me, I still have some tricks before I discard the model completely.
I will edit my question.